# graph.facebook feed returning an empty array

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Thanks in advance.

Can someone help me understand why the facebook feed is returning an empty array

https://graph.facebook.com/578431340/feed?access_token=748441095227914%7CTvThGP9sRaRPZfUbSIT6kABgytM&limit=20

```
{
  "data": [

   ]
}
```

Comment: What permissions do you have on the access token?

Comment: it was a problem with my facebook permissions on the profile. I tried the same link with a different access token.   You only need read_stream for native apps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a user access token with read_stream for user posts. Additionally the queried user needs to grant the app the read_stream permission.

You are currently using an application token.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/feed

Comment: Great answer. The permission is now called "user_posts". You can use the API explorer to request a token and test the call: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/.